# UIPickerView - getting the selection from the delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I am learning the use of UIPickerView objects and creating one programatically.  Given that it uses a delegate to call if a selection is made; what is the standard practise for getting that information to the main view controller that instantiated the picker?

I am thinking that I will use a selector to allow the delegate to send the selected row to the view controller; is there a better way?

Any assistance from someone who uses these objects regularly would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the delegate method `- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component` so that whenever a row is selected it will call this method.

You can do something like this:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSLog(@"row %d selected in component %d", row, component);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - the delegate method is below the layer of the view controller though that is handling the application.  So I have this method in the delegate but it needs to return the value to the higher level controller.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, your `UIViewController` that instantiated the `UIPickerView` will also act as its delegate (and datasource). In this case, you would assign your view controller to be the delegate of the picker, such as

```
[myPickerView setDelegate:self];
```

Then, you'll implement the method `- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component` inside your view controller. When you assign an object to be the delegate of another object, you're saying "Hey, this object knows what to do when it gets sent these delegate messages". In your case, you're saying "My main controller knows what to do when the picker sends it the didSelectRow:inComponent: message".

In doing this, you won't need to do any of that use-a-selector-to-allow-the-delegate-to-send-the-selected-row-to-the-view-controller nonsense. That is the whole point of the delegate! `UIPickerView` is "delegating" work to some other object (your controller) that knows what to do with the information contained within the selected row of the picker.

Comment: Indeed, but the issue I found is that I needed to instantiate the picker with a previously setup array of data; I couldn't find a way of passing this data into the delegate as the instantiation is handled in the background by the UIPickView init.  I think I am missing something though...